# How to tell Python multiprocessing.pool.map_async to wait in between function calls?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

Pretty much the title. I am using pool.map_async to run a program that is a black box for me. It basically analyzes files and spits out a result.

Sometimes, I need to analyze the same file twice. When I multiprocess this out, the black box program gets angry, because 2 processes are try to access the same file at once.

I cannot debug or change this black box program, but doing multiprocessing from the commandline, a 3-5 second wait between different calls (which go to different cores) resolves this issue.

Is there a way to tell map_async not to queue up everything as fast as it can, and instead wait a specified period of time in between calls?

Answer (score 0):

The correct handling would be using `locks`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes

But this requires to change the called process functions to make them respect the lock that is given to them as an arg. Without, I hardly can see an alternative to make the processes wait and your solution is good enough (although, it makes the idea of multiprocessing somehow obsolete ...)

**EDIT:**
Here is an idea how a black box program could be wrapped in wrappers using locks and that are executed by a multiprocessing pool. The work is divided into chunks so that the wrapper functions are executed stepwise in parallel. The lock garanties that when a process is executing black_box no other black_box is running at the same time.

If you know that some chunks of work are not in conflict, you could execute those black_box instances also outside the lock.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from functools import partial

# define 4 chunks of work
work = []
work.append(range(1, 5))
work.append(range(6, 10))
work.append(range(11, 15))
work.append(range(16, 20))


def black_box(i: int):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)



def wrapper(lock, work_chunk: list):
    for w in work_chunk:
        lock.acquire()
        black_box(w)
        lock.release()
    return f"chunk {work_chunk} done"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = mp.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    func = partial(wrapper, lock)
    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print(pool.map(func, work))
```

Another version where each work item has got information whether a lock is required or not:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from functools import partial

# define work with lock information
work = [(1, True), (2, False), (3, True), (4, False), (5, True), (6, False), (7, False)]


def black_box(i: int):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)



def wrapper(lock, work_item: tuple):
    if work_item[1] is True:
        lock.acquire()
        black_box(work_item[0])
        lock.release()
    else:
        black_box(work_item[0])
    return f"chunk {work_item[0]} done"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = mp.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    func = partial(wrapper, lock)
    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print(pool.map(func, work))
```

And finally a version without locks where there is delay information for each work item. The only mechanism here is that some processes are delayed by a specified amount of seconds (and hope there is no conflict ...)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

# define work with delay information
work = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0)]


def black_box(i: int):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)


def wrapper(work_item: tuple):
    time.sleep(work_item[1])
    black_box(work_item[0])
    return f"chunk {work_item[0]} done"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = mp.Manager()
    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print(pool.map(wrapper, work))
```

Comment: Changing the black box program might not be feasible, but wrapping it in a Python function that handles the locking should be doable.

Comment: If you wrap the complete black box program inside locks the multiprocessing is effectively lost. Only one process at a time will be operational and the others blocked. The idea of a lock is to have it active **only** when accessing the critical shared resource and not during the other processing parts.

Comment: You don't need to do your locking that coarse-grained. It's simple enough to base the synchronization on what files each process needs, as long as the controlling code actually knows that information.

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you have an example or concrete piece of code how to do this?

Comment: For example, one lock, a condition variable, and a set of paths for in-use files. When a process starts, it grabs the lock and checks the set. If the files it needs are available, it marks those files as in-use by adding their paths to the set. It then releases the lock and continues. If any of the files it needs are in use, it waits on the condition variable, then repeats the check when it wakes up. When a process finishes, it grabs the lock, marks that process's files as not in use (by removing their paths from the set), then calls notify_all on the condition variable.

Comment: Ok, I understand. This model assumes that there are several files and not all files are needed by all processes. So the problem is solved when sorting out which files are needed by which process at what time. However, this assumes that the wrapping Python program has got the knowledge, which files are needed by which process and when. If this knowledge is hidden inside the black bock program, you can't know it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I lost my login information, so I didn't respond for a bit.

The black box program development is out of my hands, and its not strictly predictable when each file is accessed, but running a batch file with the delay baked in fixes it, at least until said black box program has this functionality refined.

Am I correct in understanding that locking the thread can be done for a specified amount of time to achieve my desired result? As in, I could put a lock on the main program flow that releases 5 seconds after a process is called?

Comment: see EDIT in answer